# nth iteration of a function is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

**Problem:**

Let $C\subset X$ closed subset of the Banach space $X$. Suppose that for the function $K:C \to C$, its nth iteration $K^{n}:C\to C$ is a contraction. Show that $K$ has a unique fixed point.

For me this is exactly Weissinger's fixed point theorem, 
but apparently its not cause this was on a test and I got 0 on this one.

Thanks so much for the help, <3.

Comment: Is $K$ itself continuous? Was it expected to argue that $K^n$ has a unique fixed point $x_*$ by Banach fixed-point theorem, and that $Kx_*$ is also a fixed point of $K^n$, implying $x_*=Kx_*$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053405/corollary-of-banach-fixed-point-theorem this should be what are you looking for! ;)